# Applescript to Export all files in folder to pdf using Preview

Tags: applescript, macos-big-sur

I have a very large number of pdf's that I need to open in Preview, export to pdf, and close. (Some of the pdf's are pretty dodgy, so they need to be preprocessed this way.) I would like to automate this with AppleScript, but I am not making much progress. My best attempt so far is

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/mah/Desktop/Test" as alias list
end tell
repeat with f in fl
    tell application "Preview"
        open f
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
            click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
            delay 0.2
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
        end tell
        close f
    end tell
end repeat
```

This code opens all of the files, but "click menu item" has no effect, and my attempt to "click button Save" gives the error "Can’t get sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Preview". This is also the wrong way to the file, but I cannot figure out a better way.

Comment: You want to load all PDFs and save as PDFs? It sounds pointless to me, what is the purpose of that, please?

Comment: As I said in the original post, the problem is that some of the pdf's have issues (e.g., bad EOFs). Preview is very good at opening dodgy files. Exporting as PDF tells Preview to fix the file as it is saving. It works quite nicely, but would be a pain in the hiney to do this manually for 600+ files per week.

Comment: Dunno if it would help with the files you work with but if you're comfortable with the command line, you might look into mupdf. It has a 'clean' option that rewrites the pdf and can repair broken files. Assuming it worked in your case, you could then avoid the UI scripting method.

Comment: @Mockman: Your suggestion to use mutools is almost working! Now I am down to one bad file out of many hundreds. Plus, I am infinitely more comfortable with Python than Applescript. Many thanks!

Comment: @Melissa I like applescript but I do despise UI scripting and unfortunately, Preview doesn't support it well otherwise. The app 'Skim' has better applescript support but its export doesn't work exactly like Preview's so I don't think it would have solved your problem. mutools are pretty useful. Anyway, I'm glad that there was a mostly-working solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Sierra. Let me know if it works in your OS. If you have a set folder that contains your pdfs, then you can replace 'choose folder' with a reference to it. The delays may require adjustment.

**Update:** Changed source folder to one mentioned in question. Should now work with PDFs that are not associated with Preview (tested with Skim pdfs). Now exports to a specified folder (and could actually be changeable per file).

```
-- set srcFolder to choose folder -- ad hoc
set srcFolder to ((path to desktop) as text) & "Test" as alias
--> set srcFolder to alias "Drive:Users:mah:Desktop:Test:"
tell application "Finder"
    set rawFiles to (files of srcFolder whose name contains "pdf") as alias list
end tell

tell application "Preview"
    activate
    try
        close windows -- clean slate
    end try
    
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with x in rawFiles
            tell application "Preview" to open contents of x
            --> open alias "Drive:Users:mah:Desktop:Test:skim-33print-on-demand.pdf"
            --> document "skim-33print-on-demand.pdf"

            tell process "Preview"
                delay 0.2
                click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                delay 0.1
                key code 5 using {command down, shift down} -- Go to folder…
                delay 0.1
                keystroke "~/Desktop/exports/" -- folder must exist
                delay 0.1
                key code 76 -- type Return (Go button)
                delay 0.1
                key code 76 -- type Return (Save button)
                delay 0.1
                click button 1 of window 1 -- click Close button
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

NB One of the requirements of the alias is that the object it references must exist at compile time.

The specified folder may add a bit to the time required to save each pdf because of the delays for handling the UI scripting.† You can get around that by first doing a manual export as the dialogue should retain the last folder used as its target (and then remove those delays/actions). The exports folder should be empty when running the script otherwise the cancel/replace dialogue will be triggered which would require further steps in order to process. Finally, if the files do not contain 'pdf' as part of their filename then they will not be processed.

† It's actually difficult to know for sure as when the delay is set to .1, the 'go' dialogue doesn't manifest. In Script Debugger, I ran it multiple times (on six files) with the three delays each set to .1 and also at .2 seconds. So, each loop should have increased by .3 seconds, or 1.8 seconds overall. That didn't happen. In all cases, it took between 11.5 and 12 seconds to process the six files, but there was typically a .2 seconds overall increase when the delays were set to .2 (11.6 vs 11.8 seconds). Finally, I removed the six lines of code and ran it and it took between 11.4 and 11.5 seconds, so I guess the whole issue is insignificant.

Comment: @Mockman: This is oh-so-close to working for me. The one problem that has been stymieing me for the past few hours is that it only works if Preview is the default app for pdfs. If Preview is not the default app, the first file is processed fine, but the next file gets opened by the default app. I have tried everything I can think of to get around this.

Comment: @Melissa: This is because he remade your aliases list into Finder references, and opens them with System Events, and not as you had right - opening of aliases in the Preview. However, he does not even suspect that AppleScript still redirects the opening from System Events to the Finder. I did not want to indulge in extensive explanations, but I was forced.

Comment: @Melissa What happens if you replace 'open x' with 'tell application "Preview" to open x'?

Comment: @Mockman: Replacing 'open x' with 'tell application "Preview" to open x' didn't solve the problem with the second pass through the loop using the default application. In all honesty, I didn't really follow the discussion about alias lists vs Finder references in AppleScript. My knowledge of AppleScript dates back to the Hypercard days, and I have never used it much.

Comment: An 'alias' is a reference to a file/folder. 'choose file' results in an alias. Alias list is just a list of them but to dereference each item, you must get its 'contents'. Above, you would append 'as alias list' to the 'set rawFiles' line and change 'open x' to 'open (contents of x)'. I have to step out now but I'll update the script to take this approach later tonight. Some brief reading: [Aliases and Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method of accomplishing the same task, as pointed out by @Mockman, is to use mutool, a free command line pdf tool. I wrote a Python script to do this. Processing ~600 files took tens of seconds. In case anyone else has a similar problem, my code is below. Thanks to both @Monkman and @Robert Kniazidis for their help.

```
#   Usage: $ python CleanPDFs.py /Users/mah/Desktop/Test 
# 
#   This script requires the installation of mutool, a free command line pdf tool, using
#       brew install mupdf-tools
#   If you need to install brew first, follow the instructions under "Install Homebrew" at
#       https://brew.sh
#

import os
import argparse
import subprocess


def main():
    
    # Read in the arguments and validate
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Prepare a folder of downloads from Canvas for upload to Gradescope")
    parser.add_argument('subFolder', type = str, help = 'Path to folder of Canvas submissions')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    subFolder = args.subFolder

    if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
        print(f'ERROR: {subFolder} is not a valid directory.')
        exit()

    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(subFolder)

    # "Clean" all of the pdfs using mutool, outputting to a temporary file
    print("Cleaning pdfs.")
    for fn in os.listdir():
        if not fn.endswith('.pdf'):
            os.remove(fn)
        else:
            fn_out = fn + '_out'
            result = subprocess.run(["mutool", "clean", "-s", "-g", fn, fn_out])
    
    # Delete all of the unclean files
    for fn in os.listdir():
        if fn.endswith('.pdf'):
            os.remove(fn)

    # Now reclean all of the files using mutool, outputting to the original file name
    #   This may no longer be necessary, but it is very fast, so what the hey…
    print("Recleaning pdfs.")
    for fn in os.listdir():
        fn_out = fn[:-4]
        result = subprocess.run(["mutool", "clean", "-s", "-g", fn, fn_out])
         
    os.chdir(cwd)
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Worked for me… once I thought to use python 3 instead of the default on my old mac.