# AppleScript - How to set the target/path of a finder window prompt when it's prompted from an App (not from the Finder)?

Tags: user-interface, applescript

I am using AppleScript to automate a process on a GUI.

I use the script to click a button "Add Source Folder" (similar to opening a file in any apps) in the GUI, which prompts an integrated Finder window ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpar8.jpg)).

In practice, once the prompted finder window opened, I'd like the path to be set automatically from an alias object `theFolderToProcess`'s (which would've been set previously in the script).

I am unable to set its path because I have nowhere to set the alias `theFolderToProcess` within the in-app prompt finder window. So how do I get the script to navigate to the path of the alias?

Here is the code:

```
set theFolderToProcess to choose folder with prompt "Step 1: Select the folder to convert:"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "MyApp"
        tell its window "MyApp"
            activate
            click button "Add Source Folder"
            set uiElems to UI elements
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

With `UI Elements`, I get `sheet 1 of window "MyApp" of application process "MyApp" of application "System Events"` where `sheet 1` is the prompt window.

Note: Setting the path in the prompt window doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, you can't magically reach into another program's workings.

Comment: But it's a Finder window. How is it possible that it's showing you the current path, but no content element of that window is giving you this path?

Comment: Is there some reason your cannot use the `default location` _property_ of the `choose folder` _command_? Have a look at: [choose folder](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW6)

Comment: It isn't very clear, but if you are talking about some random application’s open/save dialog, note that that is _not_ a Finder window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A don't know your "App", so following example is using TextEdit. If you successfully open OPEN dialog using other way (click button "Add Source Folder"...) then replace corresponding code line of my script with yours. My script shows how to set automated delays as well. And how to click the "Go" button at the end.

```
set processName to "TexEdit"
set sourceFolder to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)

tell application processName to activate -- bring to front

tell application "System Events"
    -- this is instead of your 'click button "Add Source Folder"'
    -- it opens OPEN dialog window
    keystroke "o" using command down
    -- wait
    repeat until window "Open" of process processName exists
        delay 0.02
    end repeat
    -- open go to path sheet
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    repeat until sheet 1 of window "Open" of process processName exists
        delay 0.02
    end repeat
    -- keystroke full posix path
    keystroke sourceFolder
    -- go
    click button "Go" of sheet 1 of window "Open" of process processName
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

From within the 'open' dialogue, you should be able to use the Finder's `Go to Folder…` function, or `command-shift-G` (or whatever it is on your OS). Then use `keystroke` to enter your desired location. The location reference should follow the format below rather than using your alias. Follow up with a `key code` to accept your location. I find the short delays help with keyboard scripting but edit as desired.

```
set posixFolder to posix path of theFolderToProcess
--> "~/Desktop/exports/"

delay 0.1
key code 5 using {command down, shift down} -- Go to folder…

delay 0.1
keystroke posixFolder -- folder must exist
--> keystroke "~/Desktop/exports/" -- folder must exist

delay 0.1
key code 76 -- type Return (Go button)
```

There is a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201232/7410243) but this should be sufficient.

Comment: That's exactly it!! Thank you. Though here `sheet 1 of window "MyApp" of application process "MyApp"`, sheet 1 is where I need the keystrokes I think, so it's still not working. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @userX, instead of last code line of answer try this: **click button "Go" of sheet 1 of window "Open" of process AppName**

Comment: You don't apply keystroke to the sheet. You can see in the linked post. If you type 'command-shift-G' when the dialogue is open, does it bring up the 'go to folder' dialogue? Also, what do you mean by 'not working'? That never helps. What happens?

Comment: Yes sorry I should've explained better. You guessed right, the 'go to folder' dialogue does not appear when the dialog is open (but if I manually types, it works - thought I'd check just in case).

Comment: @userX, your Mac needs bigger delays. Here is example of automated delay:  **keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    repeat until sheet 1 of window "Open" of process processName exists
        delay 0.02
    end repeat**

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Thanks for the help. I have made the delays longer but the issue remains. And I'll be honest, I can't figure how to write your current syntax, I'm quite new to AppleScript.

Comment: @userX, also, you should keystroke full posix path. Also, you should activate (bring to front) your window before any keystrokes